# Retrieve filename of uploading file in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I've been searching for a solution on how to get the filename of using SQL Server. I know that it's possible if you're using C#. But how is it done in SQL?

For example, I have a file (example: uploadfile.txt) located in C:\ that is about to be uploaded. I have a table which has a field "filename". How do I get the filename of this file?

This is the script that I have as of the moment.

```
-- Insert to table
BULK INSERT Price_Template_Host
FROM 'C:\uploadfile.txt'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)

-- Insert into transaction log table filename and datetime()
```

Comment: You really need to elaborate more.  your question does not make sense.

Comment: is it clear now? just wondering. the idea is to get the file name "uploadfile.txt" in a select statement.

Comment: What are you using to do the uploading?

Comment: If you just want to get a value that is in the database, you would do SELECT filename from TableName WHERE ...

Comment: I'm using an sql script to upload the files.

Comment: Can you **show** us the script???  If that's your own script, I'm pretty sure you could somehow capture that file name in some way - but it would **help** to actually **see** the script....

Comment: modified my question. that's all that i have. i have a table where the information of the filename and uploaded date/time will be saved.

Comment: I don't think you can get at the file name when using BULK INSERT. What do you need that for anyway?? One way to do it would be to wrap the whole thing into a stored procedure and store the file name in a separate statement, into an Audit table or something, and then execute the BULK INSERT

Comment: What generated the filename in the script (`FROM 'C:\uploadfile.txt'
`)? or is it hard coded?

Comment: @scrum meister: it's hard coded. I'm thinking of transferring it to a dynamic one. but that's out of the issue.

Comment: @marc_s: i guess there's no possible way to do it. I guess i'll just create a windows application to get that filename.

Comment: What do you need the file name for, anyway?? Also: if you do go to a Windows app, I'd **strongly** recommend using the `SqlBulkCopy` component in .NET to get almost the same performance

Comment: the file name will be used for the log tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no direct method **in T-SQL** to locate a file on the file system. After all this is not what the language is intended to be used for. From the script you have provided, [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) requires that the fully qualified file name already be known at the time of the statement call.

There are of course a whole variety of ways you could identify/locate a file, outside of using T-SQL for example using SSIS, perhaps you could use [xp_cmdshell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) (has security caveats), or create a managed code module within SQL Server to perform this task.

To provide you with specific guidence, it may help if you could provide us all with details of the **business process** that you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally attach this problem with an SSIs package, which would give you much more flexibility in terms of load and subsequent logging. However, if you're set on doing this through T-SQL, consider exec'ing dynamically-constructed SQL:

```
declare @cmd nvarchar(max), @filename nvarchar(255)
set @filename = 'C:\uploadfile.txt'

set @cmd = 
'BULK INSERT Price_Template_Host
FROM '''+@filename+'''
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\t'',
    ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
)'

-- Debug only
print @cmd
-- Insert to table
exec(@cmd)

-- Insert into transaction log table filename and datetime()
insert into dbo.LoadLog (filename, TheTime)
values (@filename, getdate())
```

If I understand your question correctly, this paramaterizes the filename so that you can capture it further down in the script.